# resources for learning 3D basics (Python / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python, canvas, 3d

While I consider myself a reasonably competent programmer, I have no experience with even the most basic graphics programming.

Are there any recommended resources for learning the basics of 3D programming - preferably using a high-level language like Python or JavaScript?

Ideally, I'd like a simple hello world example in canvas or WebGL with a space ship moving inside a cube (all wireframes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/

Comment: Thanks, this seems very promising (lesson 10 in particular) - will work through the lessons over the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity/) is what I recommend but I've also heard about (but never tried)
[Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/) and [Worldviz Vizard](http://www.worldviz.com/products/vizard/).  If you want to build it from the ground up yourself you might try [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) though you may have to hunt for the right libraries.  Other things you might look at:[VPython](http://vpython.org/), and [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks, that all seems interesting, and will certainly come in handly once I've grasped the basics. So I'll definitely return to this after working through the WebGL tutorial Adrian posted.

Comment: Wise decision.  I think I'll do that tutorial too.